# How to align icons (two lines) symmetric without using grid

Tags: css, html, css-float, css-position

I want to align icons, that it look like the picture below. But Flexbox, Grid or tables are not allowed.

[image: How it should look]

The black bars in the picture represents only text. I've tried several things but deleted them because it was not satisfactory. Below is my current code.

What have I to change, to get the Layout in the picture?

Current code:

```css
/* ########################################################################## */
/* Global Settings */
/* ########################################################################## */

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* ########################################################################## */
/* Clearfix-Hack */
/* ########################################################################## */

.clearfix::after{
 content:"";
 clear:both;
 display: block;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Entire Page */
/* ########################################################################## */

.entire-page{
  margin: 0 15%;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Contact  */
/*  ########################################################################## */

section{
  margin: 30px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.headline{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row > div{
  display:inline-block;
}
.social-media-container > div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles5.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ########################################################################## -->
  <!-- Entire Page -->
  <!-- ########################################################################## -->
  <div class="entire-page">


    <!-- ########################################################################## -->
    <!--  Contact -->
    <!--  ########################################################################## -->

    <section>

      <div>

        <div class="headline">
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit: </span>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="icon">
            <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
            <div>
              <p>1234 – 567 890 123</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icon">
            <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
            <div>
              <p>john@doe.com</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icon">
            <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
            <div>
              <p>John Doe</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>USA</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>12345 City</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="social-media-container clearfix">
            <div class="icon">
              <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
              <div>
                <p>facebook.com/johndoe</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
              <div>
                <p>twitter.com/johndoe</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.row { vertical-align: top }` ?

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert and `text-align:center` on the container will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give with to icons in percentage and `vertical-align:top` and its parent to `text-align:center`.

```css
/* ########################################################################## */
/* Global Settings */
/* ########################################################################## */

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* ########################################################################## */
/* Clearfix-Hack */
/* ########################################################################## */

.clearfix::after{
 content:"";
 clear:both;
 display: block;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Entire Page */
/* ########################################################################## */

.entire-page{
  margin: 0 15%;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Contact  */
/*  ########################################################################## */

section{
  margin: 30px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.headline{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row > div{
  display:inline-block;
}
.social-media-container > div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon{
  text-align: center;
}

/*** solution ***/
.iconsFloat{
  text-align: center;
}
.iconsFloat .icon{
  width:32.5%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles5.css">
</head>

<body>
 <!-- ########################################################################## -->
  <!-- Entire Page -->
  <!-- ########################################################################## -->
  <div class="entire-page">


    <!-- ########################################################################## -->
    <!--  Contact -->
    <!--  ########################################################################## -->

    <section>

      <div>

        <div class="headline">
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit: </span>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix iconsFloat">
          <div class="icon">
            <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
            <div>
              <p>1234 – 567 890 123</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icon">
            <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
            <div>
              <p>john@doe.com</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icon">
            <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
            <div>
              <p>John Doe</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>USA</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>12345 City</p>
            </div>
          </div>
    <div class="icon">
              <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
              <div>
                <p>facebook.com/johndoe</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <div><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=12271612"><img></div>
              <div>
                <p>twitter.com/johndoe</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="social-media-container clearfix">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why set width to 32.5% and vertical-align:top?

Comment: Because, it have to divided 100/3 in 3 columns. Actual width should be 33.33%. But As it is `display:inline-block;` and `inline-block` keeps some space in between. So width should be little letter than actual.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the space when using inline-block?

Comment: That's also possible. if you give `font-size:0` to icons parent. Then spacing goes away and you can give `width:33.333%`. Give font-size to icons. Have a look [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0xdvzn64/).

Comment: Thanks. You're awsome.